# problems with scanf and fgets

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

I have a project due on tuesday and everything is working except this tiny spot.

```
void main ()
{
    struct CHANNEL uChan;
    int flag = 0;

    //get name of channel
    printf("Enter the name of the channel: ");
    fgets(uChan.name, 15, stdin);

    //positive check loop from cylinderVolume.c
    do
    {
        flag = 1;
        printf("Please give roughness coefficient n, channel slope, width of channel and the maximum depth: ");
        scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf ",&uChan.n, &uChan.slope, &uChan.width, &uChan.maxDepth);

        if(uChan.n <= 0.0 || uChan.slope <= 0.0 || uChan.width <= 0.0 || uChan.maxDepth <= 0.0)
          {
              printf("All values must be greater than zero.\n");
              flag = 1;
          }
        else
            flag = 0;
    } while(flag == 1);

    return;
}
```

(uChan is a structure, all of its members are defined here)
when i run this (with the rest of my code) it will request 5 inputs in the scanf line and no matter what i input into fgets, it will always output 'á'

Comment: `struct CHANNEL` - Please show the struct. And `void main` -> should that be `int main`?

Comment: Your `scanf` line reads 4 (not 5) values.

Comment: Also check the return vom `scanf`. It is there for a reason

Comment: Also after the `printf("Pl....` you will need a `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: *it will always output 'á'* Where? The program only outputs constant strings.

Answer (score 1):

A whitespace character in the format string of `scanf` (and family) intructs `scanf` to read and ignore all whitespace characters until a non-whitespace character.

In your case,

```
scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf ",&uChan.n, &uChan.slope, &uChan.width, &uChan.maxDepth);
                  //  ^ this space is causing scanf to wait until a non whitespace character
```

To fix it, remove the space

Comment: It definitely fixes *some* problem, but not necessarily the one OP is asking about.

Comment: Pretty sure it fixes the OP's "five" input problem. I can't say anything about the `fgets` problem since I can't see the full code. As for the rest of the issues, the comments seems to have covered it.